# Self containing shared_ptr of itself that is inherited from std::enable_shared_from_this

Tags: c++, inheritance, smart-pointers, this-pointer

This question is a follow up question of this question here: [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41681691/c-assigning-this-pointer-of-a-class-to-either-a-unique-ptr-or-a-shared-ptr)

I have a class that inherits from `std::enable_shared_from_this` and this class contains a `std::shared_ptr<Self>`

In any of this class's constructors after I know that the class's details are complete and successful how do I go about assigning the stored `std::shared_ptr<Self>` to be that of the `shared this`?

Example:

```
class Self : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Self> {
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Self> me_; // Or
    std::unique_ptr>Self> me_;

public:
    Self ( /*some parameters*/ );
};

Self::Self( /* some parameters */ ) {
    // Check parameters for creation

    // Some work or initialization being done

    // If all is successful and construction of this class is about
    // to leave scope, then set the smart pointer to the this*

    // How to do ...
    me_ = std::enable_shared_from_this<Self>::shared_from_this();
    // Properly if this is even possible at all.
}
```

Comment: @ Jason R oh okay then. So it would then require me to have a "manager type class" that does contain instances of them or I would need to set it in function to be called immediately after its constructor such as a construct or initialize function.

Comment: a shared_ptr to self is an oxymoron. useful only for temporarily keeping an object alive (while waiting for a callback, for example).

Answer (score 2):

You can't. At that point, the `shared_ptr` that points to the current `Self` instance doesn't exist yet. It can't possibly exist until after the constructor returns. `shared_from_this()` has a precondition that a `shared_ptr` already exists that points to `this`.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. So I would either need a Manager Class that contains the shared pointers, or have a method within this class that needs to be called after the constructor such as a create() or a init() method then.

Comment: Yeah, inheriting from this part of the library is new to me.

Comment: So now it's just a matter of which path to go down... and if I go with the manager type class, then there should be no need to have this class inherit from shared_from_this.

Comment: A slightly more abstract way of looking at it is that an object has no say regarding the ownership of itself – it can't decide to be shared.

Comment: @JasonR "_It can't possibly exist until after the constructor returns._" Technically speaking, cannot you create such pointer from ctor using `std::shared_ptr<T>(this)`. It might be bad a bad and dangerous practice, I just wanted to say that it looks possible.

Comment: @molbdnilo Just for the sake of abstract discussion. Imagine that all pointers are smart pointers (roughly speaking, as in languages with integrated garbage collector). Then it would not be an issue with self-pointing. So, I would not say it is a conceptual issue :).

Comment: @AlexD you could abuse the API in that way, yes. But then you would need to be careful to either ensure that the shared_ptr doesn't go out of scope, or provide a custom deleter to it. Otherwise, at the end of the constructor, the smart pointer would go out of scope and delete the object you just created.

Comment: @JasonR Sure, I understand that it is a dubious practice, just tried to say that "_it cannot possibly exist_" is too restrictive :).

Answer (score 1):

You can't because you must be an existing `std::shared_ptr` that points to the current object. As Scott Meyers says in Effective Modern C++ (chapter 19), you could declare your constructors private, and make a factory function returning a `std::shared_ptr`, like :

```
class Self: public std::enable_shared_from_this<Self> {
public:
// factory function that perfect-forwards args
// to a private ctor
    template<typename... Ts>
    static std::shared_ptr<Self> create(Ts&&... params);
    ...
    void process();
    ...
private:
    ... // ctors
};
```

And then call `process`, that could be something like:

```
void Self::process() 
{
    ... 
    me_ = shared_from_this();
}
```

Comment: I think it is technically possible (although might be a bad design). See my comment to JasonR's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41683759/3246555).